# localStorage is not saving values of similar names

Tags: javascript, local-storage

My `localStorage` is only saving a few variables (3) of similar names, and then proceeding to override the last variable with the new value.

What I am trying to do is add variables into `localStorage` that have a name and a number attached to them such as **Test1**, **Test2**, **Test3**, etc.

The only issue is that after the third element, in this case **Test3**, the key gets overridden to **Test4** and the value changes to the new value. This happens forever as long as the word **Test** is the same.

I can add other values just fine, but only up to 3 of the same root word.

This is the code I am using to add the elements:

```
const AddToLocalStorage = (type, contents) => {
    let ind = 0;
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key == (type + ind)) {
            ind++;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
    localStorage.setItem((type + ind), JSON.stringify(contents));
}
```

`type` is a string such as **Test**
`contents` is the value stored

Thanks in advance :)

*Edit - Can you clarify how to call the `AddToLocalStorage` function*

```
AddToLocalStorage("Test", "value");
```

In `localStorage` this would set like `{ "Test0", "value" }`

Comment: The `setItem` is outside the `forEach` so it makes sense only the last value is written.

Comment: @0stone0 Can you elaborate? Why would the `setItem` need to be inside the `forEach` loop?

Comment: Could you please clarify how you call the `AddToLocalStorage` function?

Comment: Why not use an array?

Comment: @adiga I am using `localStorage` because I am using the values set on multiple pages. If you mean using an array in `localStorage`, how would I do this? I thought you could only set strings

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` always returns an string. Something like this: `const AddToLocalStorage = (type, contents) => { const arr = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem(type) || "[]" ); arr.push(contents); localStorage.setItem(type, JSON.stringify(arr) ); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, JavaScript Object Property order [isn't guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), therefore you're probably not receiving the keys in the same order as your browser shows them

---

That said, lets add some `console.log`'s to debug the code:

```js
const AddToLocalStorage = (type, contents) => {
    let ind = 0;
    console.log('Existing keys', Object.keys(localStorage));
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key == (type + ind)) {
            ind++;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
    console.log('Set', (type + ind))
    localStorage.setItem((type + ind), JSON.stringify(contents));
}
AddToLocalStorage("Test", "value1");
```

On the second run, this logs:

```
Existing keys (3) ["Test2", "Test0", "Test1"]
Set Test2
```

Here we can see that `(type + ind)` will be `Test2`, because `(key == (type + ind))` will be `true` for `Test1` and `Test2`.

Since `Test2` already exists, you'll override the existing value.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Such a stupid mistake

Comment: Basically the "error" here is assuming that `localStorage` will give keys back in the same order that you set them. That is an incorrect assumption. The correct way to do this would be to either save one big array in storage, or have a separate item in storage called `nextIndex` or whatever.

Comment: Yea @Nietthedarkabsol, trying to find a SO post to link to to let OP know more about this. So far not found

Comment: @0stone0 Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order